# MySQL - Gets coordinates la/lon out of

Tags: mysql

I have a set of longitude/latitude coordinates of a city polygon stored in a MySQL table, field type polygon.

```
POLYGON((5.2014358 51.0733048, 5.2027865 51.0751707, 5.2031699 51.0743929, 5.202271 51.0741138))
```

I want to execute a MySQL command, selecting all coordinates in this field, like:

```
longitude latitude
5.2014358 51.0733048
5.2027865 51.0751707
5.2031699 51.0743929
5.202271 51.0741138
```

How can I do this in a MySQL select command?

Comment: Is using `ST_AsText(...)` an option? Or any function on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-polygon-property-functions.html

Comment: It’s an option but can’t get it out with that function